# Remove last , in php string

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Hello I have this example

I need to delete the last comma

```
<?php

$numeri = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V'];

$size = count($numeri);
for ($i = $size - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $a = $numeri[$i]  . ',';
    echo $a;
 
}


?>
```

V, IV, III , II, I,

But even if I use substr or substrl_replace it deletes all the commas.

Comment: _"I need to delete the last comma"_ - a) `rtrim` exists, and b) why did you _add_ it in the first place then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `join()` function here:

```php
$numeri = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V'];
$output = join(",", array_reverse($numeri));
echo $output;  // V,IV,III,II,I
```

If you want to stick with a loop approach, then use logic to prepend a comma at each iteration, except for the very first:

```php
$numeri = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V'];

$size = count($numeri);
$a = null;
for ($i = $size - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($a) $a .= ",";
    $a .= $numeri[$i];
}

echo $a;  // V,IV,III,II,I
```

Comment: I was just about to answer the same using `implode`, when did it become `join`? :)

Comment: As you see I need to print the array in reverse. That's why I used the for loop

Comment: @Kida Missed that, sorry.  Just use `join()` along with `array_reverse()`.  Or, use a loop as I have done so in the second part of my answer.

Comment: @IanBrindley [join](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.join.php) is an alias of implode, implode still exists

Comment: I can't believe this question still gets answered

Answer (score 0):

substring will work if you do operation after for loop

```html
<?php

$numeri = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V'];

$size = count($numeri);
for ($i = $size - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $a=$a.$numeri[$i]  . ',';
}
$a=substr($a,0,strlen($a)-1);
echo $a;
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$mystring='['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V']';
$myString = trim($myString, ',');
 echo $myString;
```

Comment: `$mystring` is an invalid string that will cause a "parse error". `$myString` doesn't exist yet when using `trim`, you named it `$mystring`. `['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V']` should be an array, not a string. `trim` will _not_ remove the last comma here